Getting Range not found when using getRange()
Every time I use getRange in my program (lines 8 and 11), I get an error




Exception: Range not found,

but I cannot figure out why.
I tried using getA1notation() and toString() , but both resulted in the same error.
Code as text:
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

function rangeAsNote(targCell, targRange) {
  //Sets up output string
  let rangeAsString = new String();
  //Creates new var "cell" and sets it to the inputted range of cells
  var cell = sheet.getRange(targCell);

  //Sets "rangeAsString" to "targRange" converted to the desired format using rangeToString()
  rangeAsString = rangeToString(sheet.getRange(targRange));

  //Sets the note of "cell" to "rangeAsString"
  cell.setNote(rangeAsString);

  return;
}


The documentation says that if you call your function with a reference to a single cell as an argument, the argument will be the value of the cell. and if you call your function with a reference to a range of cells as an argument, the argument will be a two-dimensional array of cells' values. So, targCell and targRange are not references to ranges, but the actual values of the cells that are specified, either as a single value, or an array of values. Apps Script Functions

Let's start by saying that what you are trying to do is not possible because custom functions in Google Sheets can only return values; they can't be used to modify the spreadsheet.
Let's delve into the specific question. The error message you're encountering is likely due to the cell/range references used as parameters of custom functions in Google Sheets and Google Apps Script. These references return the cell / range values, not the string required by the SpreasheetApp.Sheet.getRange method. Understanding this will help you troubleshoot more effectively.
Instead of
=rangeAsNote(A1, E1:G1)

the simplest solution is to use text values as parameters, as shown below:
=rangeAsNote("A1", "E1:G1")

However, as mentioned on top of these answers, this will not work as you expect due to custom function limitations. Use another method to call the function:

Use a Custom menu item.
Assign the function to an image.
Use a Google Apps Script trigger.
Run the function from a dialog, sidebar or web application created using the HTML Service.
Run the function from the Apps Script editor.

This might imply making modifications to the function to pass the required parameters.

If custom functions are unable to do this, how are functions like setNote() and setValue() supposed to do anything?

Use another method to call the function: a custom menu, assign the function to an image, use a trigger, call it from the Apps Script editor, or create a dialog, sidebar or web application.
